# Software that brings auto-complete everywhere

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a simple tool working with windows 7 and free/open source which allows me to maintain multiple templates and type them in any text programm/text field (Word, email client, Browser).

Perfectly I press some keys, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (or <kbd>WIN</kbd>) and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and a pop up appears where I can type some letters until my template is selected and I press enter and the text is pasted. Every template should contain a title and the text. Variables like date and time are a plus but not necessary.

Clarification: to enter some letters like `fdh#` and the last letter replaces my text with another text does not help, because I need a lot of templates and I don't like to remember which letters brings me to my needed template.

Comment: This is a great question. If you have found more answers I really appreciate if you could please share them with us. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### [Phrase Express](http://www.phraseexpress.com/)

Phrase Express is a text auto-complete software for Windows. Its features include:

> - Organize frequently used text snippets.
> - Expand abbreviations in any program.
> - Automate repetitive tasks.
> - Auto-complete phrases.
> - Quick access to the Windows Clipboard History.
> - Correct spelling mistakes in any application.
> - Available for Windows and Android!
> - Free for personal use

You can also configure the pop-up shortcut under `Hotkeys` in the settings window:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After trying many, I have personally found [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) to be the best all round Windows clipboard manager.

And, yes, of course it supports boilerplate text (and other formats; you could boilerplate some Excel cells if you wanted to, or graphics, etc). I use this feature and am surprised to see that it is not listed on the website. rest assured, it does work.

> Ditto is an extension to the standard windows clipboard. It saves each
>   item placed on the clipboard allowing you access to any of those items
>   at a later time. Ditto allows you to save any type of information that
>   can be put on the clipboard, text, images, html, custom formats, .....

```
 - Easy to use interface  
 - Search and paste previous copy entries  
 - Keep multiple computer's clipboards in sync  
 - Data is encrypted when sent over the network  
 - Accessed from tray icon or global hot key  
 - Select entry by double click, enter key or drag drop  
 - Paste into any window that excepts standard copy/paste entries  
 - Display thumbnail of copied images in list  
 - Full Unicode support(display foreign characters)  
 - UTF-8 support for language files(create language files in any language)  
 - Uses sqlite database (www.sqlite.org)
```

[image]